# ping to the 4.2.2.2 is not working. what to do?

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, ping, connect

Network connectivity is good.
ping to the 4.2.2.2 is not working. 
I also want to know why we ping to the 4.2.2.2.
ping -n 4.2.2.2

Comment: When I learned Cisco, everyone taught us to use 4.2.2.2 because it was easy to remember and publicly pingable. I think 8.8.8.8 was a later development, but currently the preferred (on less number to remember).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4.2.2.2 is one of the easiest to type of a collection of 6 DNS servers at 4.2.2.1 through 4.2.2.6 (originally only 1-3). The answer queries made by the general public

Should I Use 4.2.2.2?

Unless you are a Level-3 customer, absolutely not. Google now has established public DNS servers at 8.8.8.8 which you should use. 8.8.4.4 can additionally be used, but 8.8.8.8 is pretty easy.

If your are not able to ping 4.2.2.2 you can check with your ISP or firewall config, if your interent is working then your DNS might be different from 4.2.2.2 you can check in network status in windows and /etc/resolve.conf in linux or networking settings

Also its better to use DNS ip's provided by ISP if not then use google DNS 8.8.8.8 or 8.8.4.4